# Algebraic intuition of the Levi-Civita connection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, intuition, connections

I was wondering about the difference between the algebraic approach to the Levi-Civita connection and the purely geometric one. Let me explain myself a little better.

So, I'm just entering the world of algebraic geometry, and I came across [this tweet](https://twitter.com/SamuelGWalters/status/1400627009525469186) which shows a method of building the Levi-Civita connection by way of rings, modules and derivations. Then I read further and saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618882/levi-civita-connection-intuition-and-motivation) whose answer is with manifolds, tangent bundles and connections. I'm wondering whether the intuition I've built up until this point is valid or not; that the algebraic approach is basically using the "abstract structure" of the space to deduce the connection, and the manifold route studies the geometric object itself. Sorry if I can't explain myself in clear terms.

I tried to figure this out by writing the two methods in parallel and trying to relate the two, but I got lost in a sea of complicated math which I don't understand yet. Also, if anyone can point me in the direction of relevant literature that would be much appreciated!

Comment: As far as I understand, here is the connection between two definitions: For a smooth manifold $M$, we have an algebra $A=C^{\infty}(M)$ of $C^{\infty}$-functions on $M$; derivations on $A$ can be identified with $\Gamma(M,TM)$, vector fields on $M$; a Riemannian metric on $M$ is a (some adjectives...) map from $\Gamma(M,TM)\times \Gamma(M,TM)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ (this can be identified with $TM\times TM\to R$); a linear connection on $M$ is a (some adjectives ...) map $\Gamma(M,TM)\times \Gamma(M,TM)\to \Gamma(M,TM)$. Such map is Levi-Civita if it satisfies precisely the equation in the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there may seem to be a disconnect when using coordinates and Christoffel symbols, many modern texts will develop the notion of vector fields and connections in a way which maps directly onto the algebraic definitions. The important correspondences are the following:

1. The set of smooth functions $M\to\mathbb{R}$, denoted $C^\infty M$, forms a commutative ring under pointwise multiplication.
2. Let $\mathfrak{X}M$ be the $C^\infty M$-module of smooth vector fields on $M$. Every element $X\in\mathfrak{X}M$ corresponds to a "directional derivative" map $X:C^\infty M\to C^\infty M$. In fact, this map is a derivation, and $\mathfrak{X}M$ is isomorphic to the module of derivations of $C^\infty M$. Additionally, the Lie bracket of vector fields corresponds to the canonical Lie bracket of derivations.
3. Every $(0,2)$ tensor field $T$ can act on a pair of vector fields, giving a map $T:\mathfrak{X}M\times\mathfrak{X}M\to C^\infty M$. Such a map corresponds to a
   tensor field iff it is $C^\infty M$-bilinear. In fact, the space of $(0,2)$ tensor fields is isomorphic to the space of $C^\infty M$-bilinear forms $\mathfrak{X}M\times\mathfrak{X}M\to C^\infty M$. Furthermore, such a tensor field is symmetric/nondegenerate in the geometric sense iff the corresponding $C^\infty M$-bilinear form is symemetric/nondegenerate in the algebraic sense.

These give an algebraic definition of vector fields and covariant $(0,2)$ tensor fields in terms of the ring $C^\infty M$. Of course, these geometric objects can be defined in many other ways, some of which make their algebraic properties less obvious. For a much more detailed discussion, see for instance Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (in particular the chapters on vector fields and tensors).

With the above correspondences established, one can see that the algebraic and geometric treatments of connections are quite similar:

A *connection* on the module of derivations $\mathfrak{D}$ of a commutative ring $R$ is a map $\nabla:\mathfrak{D}\times\mathfrak{D}\to\mathfrak{D}$, with the following properties (throughout, let $X,Y,Z\in\mathfrak{D}$, and $f,g\in R$):

- $R$-linearity in the first argument: $\nabla_{fX+gY}Z=f\nabla_XZ+g\nabla_YZ$
- additivity in the second argument: $\nabla_X(Y+Z)=\nabla_XY+\nabla_XZ$
- Leibniz rule: $\nabla_X(fY)=X(f)Y+f\nabla_XY$

They can also have some additional properties:

- A a connection $\nabla$ is said to be *torsion free* if it satisfies $\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX=[X,Y]$
- Given an $R$-bilinear form $h:\mathfrak{D}\times\mathfrak{D}\to R$, we say that $\nabla$ is *compatible with $h$* if $X(h(Y,Z))=h(\nabla_XY,Z)+h(X,\nabla_XZ)$.

An *affine connection* on a smooth manifold $M$, meanwhile, is defined exactly as above, but with $R=C^\infty M$ and $\mathfrak{D}=\mathfrak{X}M$. Further, given a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ we say that $\nabla$ is *compatible with $g$* if it is compatible with the corresponding $C^\infty M$-bilinear form $g:\mathfrak{X}M\times\mathfrak{X}M\to C^\infty M$.